# How do I see the information for the second hard drive on Get-VMScsiController?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I want to see a list of hard drives on the scsi controller. in Powershell

```
Get-VMScsiController -VMName 'server name' -ControllerNumber 0
```

Result:

Drives -----

> {Hard Drive on SCSI controller number 0 at location 0, Hard Dri...

How do I see the information for the second hard drive? It just shows ...

Answer (score 0):

Using [Get-VMHardDiskDrive](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/hyper-v/get-vmharddiskdrive?view=win10-ps)

Get-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName 'server name' -ControllerNumber 0 -ControllerLocation 1 -ControllerType SCSI